# Function allowed and not allowed for export in my shared library written in C - public and private ones

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I've created my own shared library in C - *.so. How can I mark functions that I want to export from it and ones I don't want to? By making them public and private ones or something similar. In other words, functions that should be visible to clients and functions  that shouldn't.

Comment: In C you really can't do that except using the `static` keyword. GCC have [function *attributes*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) to hide symbols though.

Answer (score 0):

**If information this will work for you**
https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Exported-Symbols-of-Shared-Libraries.html